# Byte array is being returned but not notifying the end user to open it in Excel

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, csv

I am trying to return a csv file from a controller as a byte array.  However my IE browser is not prompting the user to open this CSV in an Excel Doc.

**This is my controller**

```
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("HomeController.cs");

    public ActionResult GetClientList (int? marketId, int? partnerId, int? statusId, int? officeId)
    {
        List<Engagement> QueryResult = PMService.GetRequestedEngagments(marketId, partnerId, statusId,officeId);

        try
        {
          /* I am sending my query list to a function which
             creates it to a Comma seprated string in order 
             to be become a CSV file.*/

            var writetofile = PMService.BuildCsvString(QueryResult);

            var bytefile = new byte[writetofile.Count()];

            return bytefile;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
        }
            return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `BuildCsvString` returns the CSV file as a string. So you could return this result as a FileResult that will be downloaded by the user:

```
string writetofile = PMService.BuildCsvString(QueryResult);
var bytefile = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writetofile);
return File(bytefile, "text/csv", "test.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`FileResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult(v=vs.118).aspx) as the return type rather than `ActionResult`.

For example

```
public FileResult GetClientList() 
{
   var writetofile = PMService.BuildCsvString(QueryResult);
   var bytefile = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(writetofile);

   return File(byteFile, "text/csv","yourFileName.csv");
}
```

Comment: This is just going to return a big byte array of zeros. You have only instantiated the `bytefile` array variable with some size but never actually wrote any content into it. So the result that will be streamed to the client browser will be some array of voids.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - nice spot.  I copied the OP's original code from the question assuming it worked.  He can either use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` as you have recommended or `File.ReadAllBytes` if the BuildCSVString method does not work as expected.